# How to slicing image and make it stretchable with image assets

Tags: ios, xcode, ios7, storyboard, uiimageasset

stretch image right and left side 
centre arrow remain as it is

[image]

i tried with it but centre down arrow position is not properly set by me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do this with sliced images.

The area between the edges will stretch or repeat in order to fill the area. You can't also preserver the centre section of an image this way.

What you might be better doing is creating a custom drawn view using either CALayer or drawRect.